# A different situation in switch case

Tags: c

I was doing a simple vowel and consonant problem using switch case in C programming but getting different output. The program is directly visiting the default case of switch. It may be that case is not able to recognise the condition.

The condition is :

```c
case 'a'||'e'||'i'||'o'||'u':
  printf("vowel");
  break;
default:
  printf("consonant");
```

Comment: Because that's not how case alternatives are done in C. Your case label equals to `(char)1`, field separator in ASCII.

Comment: @bipll: It is just `1`; character literals have `int` type in C, not `char`. And case labels are converted to the type of the controlling expression (the expression in the `switch`) anyway. Also, the controlling expression is subject to the integer promotions, so it is at least `int`, not `char`.

Answer (score 4):

`case 'a'||'e'||'i'||'o'||'u': printf("vowel");` is equivalent too `case 1: printf("vowel");`.

(All character literals other than `'\0'` are truthy, so the `case` expression yields `1`, which in ASCII would correspond to an unprintable character called [start of heading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), which you shouldn't find in a text file.)

What you need is:

```
case 'a': case 'e': case 'i': case 'o': case 'u': printf("vowel");
```

i.e. (depending on how you look at it) multiple `case` labels attached to the same `printf` statement or several cases with implicit fall-through in between them.